# Prevent browser from opening two tabs when clicking link inside <div>

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, hyperlink

I have the following code. The problem is that the browser opens two tabs when clicking the `<a>` element.

The `md-toolbar` element opens a link once it is clicked by triggering the `openLink()` function. However, when clicking the `<a>` element, the browser (Firefox only) opens two tabs from both links in `md-toolbar` and `<a>`

```html
<md-toolbar ng-click="$ctrl.openLink('https://youtube.com')">
  <div layout="row" layout-align="space-between center" class="md-toolbar-tools">
      <a ng-click="$ctrl.openLink('https://google.com')">
        <md-button>
          Google
        </md-button>
      </a>
  </div>
</md-toolbar>
```

Is there a solution that prevents the browser from opening both links?

Comment: if I try to access $ctrl insde `onclick` it errors out saying `$ctrl` is no defined

Comment: Use `ng-click="$event.stopPropagation();$ctrl.openLink('https://google.com')"`

Comment: @georgeawg thaanks! that worked